# Is there a way to send unique emails to multiple recipients without Loops, BCC or Pear::Mail in PHP?

Tags: php, email

I know that this question is similar to other multiple-email-recipient-questions, but none of them gives me a solution that I can use...

I am trying to send newsletter emails to registered users. Each newsletter will include an "unsubscribe"-link that is unique for each user. The number of users increases more and more which makes it more and more difficult/inefficient to send newsletters to them. I have read about and tried different solutions:

1. Send one email with `mail()` for each user. I.e. loop over the users and send one email to each user. The advantage is that I can configure the email contents with unique "unsubscribe"-links for each individual user. BUT! This is not efficient and it is not recommended by PHP:s manual: "*The mail function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient*". I have noticed that it takes about 1 second to send one single email.
2. Use "Bcc" to list all users as recipients in one single email. This is more efficient and I only need to send one single email to all users at once. But this means that I can't include an "unsibscribe"-link that is unique to each user.
3. Use Pear::Mail. This sounds interesting... However, for me that's not possible since my website exists on a web hosting service and I am not able to install Pear::Mail (or can I???)

These are the only three methods that I am aware of that I could use. But none of them seems to be enough for me. Are there any other solutions to look at? Or have I missed something else?

Comment: I would really advice to look into other existing transactional e-mail solutions like Mandrill, Mailgun, etc. If you don't want to use these, I recommend creating a job queue for the e-mails.

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, chances are your outgoing SMTP is configured with some rate limiting. It's unlikely that you'll find the configured thresholds before you send out your emails, and it's not even likely that you'll be able to unambiguously detect a rate limit. If this is even permitted under the FUP. You're better off using @Daan's suggestion and go with a transactional API.

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails from your own host, especially from a shared host is not a good idea.

As your users are growing, you should try using any transactional email service provider such as Mailgun, SendGrid, etc.

Now let's talk about how should you approach it.

1. Sending emails takes time, so you need to create something like a job queue that will send your email in the background.
2. You can also use cron jobs to run your script from time to time and send emails in batch.